# Get SharePoint Versions with all the properties including custom properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query

Is there any possiblities to read SharePoint item's version with all the properties (including the custom properties) for SharePoint Online ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the CSOM/REST APIs do unfortunately not support this yet! But seems the SharePoint Team at Microsoft is [thinking about it](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147150-provide-items-version-history-with-csom). I would also love to see support for this.